# integrating available components with ROS

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have different robot application components, all written in C++, separately working. I would like to use only the communication capabilities of ROS, i.e Messages, Services and networking multiple PCs, to integrate these components. Is there any tutorial for this? Could someone please give me some hints how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53514/integrating-available-components-with-ros/) by [mr_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/3644/mr_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do the basic ROS tutorials for c++ first:
http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

Then you can write ROS nodes which use you existing c++ libraries and provide the messaging interfaces. For networking on multiple PCs, look here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2